# datatables Individual column searching (select inputs) in a different element than footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to eddit the options in the datatables example for using select inputs and their example works fine. However i would like this to work on another element that I've built a dropdown list.

I've got it so that it populates the dropdown list which is great however if i click on any of the options nothing happens. I have tried changing the `.on "change"` to `"click"` but i just get a `.replace` does not support this object.

here is my code.

```
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="htmToolbar">
    <ul class="nav-xs" id="htmTools">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a style="cursor: pointer;">Manufacturer &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></a>
            <ul id="Manufacturer" class="dropdown-menu" id="StartersTool">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Filter By</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="htmToolbar">
    <ul class="nav-xs" id="htmTools">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a style="cursor: pointer;">Software Tag &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></a>
            <ul id="SoftwareTag" class="dropdown-menu" id="StartersTool">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Filter By</li>      
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="htmToolbar">
    <ul class="nav-xs" id="htmTools">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a style="cursor: pointer;">Status &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></a>
                <ul id="Status" class="dropdown-menu" id="StartersTool">
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Filter By</li>
                </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is my Js code that is inside a function.

```
$('#Ttable').DataTable
       ({
                initComplete: function () 
                    {
                    this.api().columns([1,3,4]).every( function () 
                    {
                        var column = this;
                        var select = $('<li style="width:300px;" class="pickList Manlist"></li>')
                            .appendTo( $("#Manufacturer"))
                            .on( 'click', function () 
                            {
                                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex
                                (
                                    $(this).val()
                                );
                                console.log(val);
                                column
                                    .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                    .draw();
                            });
                        column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) 
                        {
                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'" class="dropdown-item">'+d+'</option>' )
                        });
                    });
                    },
                    scrollY:"500px",
                    scrollCollapse: true
            }


        );
```

any help would be really useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues are what you append and how you register the click events.

First, you were appending `<option>` to a `<ul>`... Which is obviously invalid markup. I suggest you to use some `<li>`.

Second, you were registering the click event on the whole `<ul>` instead of the `<option>` (now `<li>`) the user clicks on. That is why the `.val()` method to get the value of the option was failing.

Third, Since you should use `<li>`, change `.val()` for `.text()`.

Here is a demo:

```js
$('#Ttable').DataTable({
  initComplete: function(){
    
    // Have this variable accessible for the whole initComplete
    var column;
    
    // Iterate the column
    this.api().columns([1]).every( function(){

      column = this;
      var select = $('<li style="width:300px;" class="pickList Manlist"></li>')
      .appendTo( $("#Manufacturer"));

      column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ){
        select.append( '<li class="dropdown-item">'+d+'</li>' );
      });
    });
    
    // Once all appendings are done, register a click handler
    $("#Manufacturer li.dropdown-item").on( 'click', function(){
        var val = $(this).text();
        console.log(val);

        column
          .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
          .draw();
      });
  },
  scrollY:"500px",
  scrollCollapse: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="htmToolbar">
  <ul class="nav-xs" id="htmTools">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a style="cursor: pointer;">Manufacturer &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></a>
      <ul id="Manufacturer" class="dropdown-menu" id="StartersTool">
        <li class="dropdown-header">Filter By</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<table id="Ttable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>column 1</th>
      <th>column 2</th>
      <th>column 3</th>
      <th>column 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>something 1</td>
      <td>something 2</td>
      <td>something 3</td>
      <td>something 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>something 5</td>
      <td>something 6</td>
      <td>something 7</td>
      <td>something 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>something 9</td>
      <td>something 10</td>
      <td>something 11</td>
      <td>something 12</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/LqvKGL?editors=1011)

Comment: Thanks I oringonally started with <li> tags but could get it to work. Now i just have to work out how to do this for a couple of different dropdowns at the same time.

Comment: Use different `<li>` classes for each dropdown... ;)

Comment: Thanks but could you show me in your example i've been bagging my head against this for hours and i can't see what you mean. i've edited my question with the 3 dropdowns and added the 1,3,4 array columns in the JS

Comment: That's simple... Basically, just duplicate the code for each column which you want to be searched with a drop down and instead of using `dropdown-item` in the click handler, use a specific class for each column. A class that you will add when appending the `<li>`.